# Running NDK projects on Android

Tags: android, pdf, android-ndk, pdfrenderer, pdf-rendering

I'm trying to develop part of an application that would enable it to render PDF file's pages into Bitmap, or to display it on a viewer. I'm looking for a free open-source one. I've already tried a bunch of them, for example, [droidreader](http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/), and [android-pdf](http://code.google.com/p/android-pdf/). The problem is that I think it needs NDK to be able to run, I keep getting errors when trying to build it on Eclipse, even though I'm importing it directly with SVN. Can anybody refer me to a good step by step tutorial that would help me at least run those projects?

Comment: fyi. Both of the mentiond projects are GPL or commercial. i.e. they are not free!

Answer (score 0):

Just download [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

And then run in project folder following command:

```
[path to ndk]/ndk-build
```

More information on [Android NDK page](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#GetStarted)